# VBA module overwrites values

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

have problem with overwriting values. Namely, when I enter more than one value, which my module grab and verify on certain database, it overwrites already imported information verified from 1st value in the same row.

It should actually store information in the same row from where the value has been imported.
Little illustration

```
No.  Entered Values    How it stores   / How it should be stored
1.   111               *333imported*     *111imported*
2.   222                                 *222imported*
3.   333                                 *333imported*
```

My code

```
Sub SearchGB()
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim ele As Object
Dim t As Date
Dim GrantNum As String
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Integer
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim Addme As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Great Britain")
Set Addme = wsh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
Set rng = wsh.Range("B4:B100")

For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If InStr(1, cell, "EP") > 0 Then
    GrantNum = cell

Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10 '<==Adjust wait time

If InStr(1, GrantNum, "EP") = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Please enter correct form of Grant Number"
    Else
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.navigate "https://www.ipo.gov.uk/p-ipsum/Case/PublicationNumber/" & GrantNum
End If

While objIE.Busy Or objIE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
t = Timer
Do
    DoEvents
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ele = objIE.document.getElementById("externalcontent")
    If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
    On Error GoTo 0
Loop While ele Is Nothing

j = 0

With wsh
Set ele = objIE.document.getElementById("MainContent_BibliographyViewUserControl_BibliographyTable").getElementsByTagName("td")
For i = 0 To ele.Length - 1
        If Trim$(ele.Item(i).innerText) = "Applicant / Proprietor" Then
            Addme.Cells(j, 8).Value = ele.Item(i + 1).innerText
        End If
        If Trim$(ele.Item(i).innerText) = "Application Number" Then
            Addme.Cells(j, 3).Value = ele.Item(i + 1).innerText
        End If
        If Trim$(ele.Item(i).innerText) = "Publication Number" Then
            Addme.Cells(j, 5).Value = ele.Item(i + 1).innerText
        End If
        If Trim$(ele.Item(i).innerText) = "Status" Then
            Addme.Cells(j, 7).Value = ele.Item(i + 1).innerText
        End If
        If Trim$(ele.Item(i).innerText) = "Grant Date" Then
            Addme.Cells(j, 6).Value = ele.Item(i + 1).innerText
        End If
        If Trim$(ele.Item(i).innerText) = "Filing Date" Then
            Addme.Cells(j, 4).Value = ele.Item(i + 1).innerText
        End If
    Next i
    End With
    End If
Next cell
'objIE.Quit
End Sub
```

wherever I write `j = j + 1` it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your codes in column A or set the code there, the j = 0 must be outside the for Each cell, and increment only if you accept the condition, make the necessary adaptations there. good luck.

```
Sub SearchGB()
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim ele As Object
Dim t As Date
Dim GrantNum As String
Dim GrantNum2 As String
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Integer
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim Addme As range
Dim rng As range
Dim cell As range

Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Great Britain")
Set Addme = wsh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
Set rng = wsh.range("A1:A10")

j = 0

For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If InStr(1, cell, "EP") > 0 Then
    GrantNum = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Great Britain").Cells(1, 1).Value 'cell
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Great Britain").Cells(1, 2).Value = Left(GrantNum, Len(GrantNum) - 2)
    GrantNum2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Great Britain").Cells(1, 2).Value 'cell

Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10 '<==Adjust wait time

If InStr(1, GrantNum, "EP") = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please enter correct form of Grant Number"
        Else
    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.navigate "https://www.ipo.gov.uk/p-ipsum/Case/PublicationNumber/" & GrantNum2
    End If
    
    While objIE.Busy Or objIE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    t = Timer
    Do
        DoEvents
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ele = objIE.document.getElementById("externalcontent")
        If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        On Error GoTo 0
    Loop While ele Is Nothing
    
    j = j + 1
    
    With wsh
        Set ele = objIE.document.getElementById("MainContent_BibliographyViewUserControl_BibliographyTable").getElementsByTagName("td")
        For i = 0 To ele.Length - 1
            If Trim$(ele.Item(i).innerText) = "Applicant / Proprietor" Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Great Britain").Cells(j + 1, "H").Value = ele.Item(i + 1).innerText
            ElseIf Trim$(ele.Item(i).innerText) = "Application Number" Then
               ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Great Britain").Cells(j + 1, "C").Value = ele.Item(i + 1).innerText
            ElseIf Trim$(ele.Item(i).innerText) = "Publication Number" Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Great Britain").Cells(j + 1, "E").Value = ele.Item(i + 1).innerText
            ElseIf Trim$(ele.Item(i).innerText) = "Status" Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Great Britain").Cells(j + 1, "G").Value = ele.Item(i + 1).innerText
            ElseIf Trim$(ele.Item(i).innerText) = "Grant Date" Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Great Britain").Cells(j + 1, "F").Value = ele.Item(i + 1).innerText
            ElseIf Trim$(ele.Item(i).innerText) = "Filing Date" Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Great Britain").Cells(j + 1, "D").Value = ele.Item(i + 1).innerText
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End If
Next cell
'objIE.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: it inserts the values in correct column, but now in different rows.. and again it overwrites already imported values. I can see exactly how information from first value are imported and then replaced with last imported values.

Comment: I try send solucion, but this site show err to save, wait i send you before.   The j = 0 must be outside the for Each cell, and increment only if you accept the condition

Comment: great got it! the way you asked it was easy to help. count on us.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you friend, I DID IT! :) with some mixture of your and mine previous code I finally  succeed!

```
Sub SearchGB()
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim ele As Object
Dim t As Date
Dim GrantNum As String
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Integer
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim Addme As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Great Britain")
Set Addme = wsh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
Set rng = wsh.Range("B2:B100")

j = 0

For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If InStr(1, cell, "EP") > 0 Then
    GrantNum = cell

Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10 '<==Adjust wait time

If InStr(1, GrantNum, "EP") = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Please enter correct form of Grant Number"
    Else
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.navigate "https://www.ipo.gov.uk/p-ipsum/Case/PublicationNumber/" & GrantNum
End If

While objIE.Busy Or objIE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
t = Timer
Do
    DoEvents
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ele = objIE.document.getElementById("externalcontent")
    If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
    On Error GoTo 0
Loop While ele Is Nothing

j = j + 1

With wsh
Set ele = objIE.document.getElementById("MainContent_BibliographyViewUserControl_BibliographyTable").getElementsByTagName("td")
For i = 0 To ele.Length - 1
        If Trim$(ele.Item(i).innerText) = "Applicant / Proprietor" Then
                wsh.Cells(j + 1, "H").Value = ele.Item(i + 1).innerText
            ElseIf Trim$(ele.Item(i).innerText) = "Application Number" Then
               wsh.Cells(j + 1, "C").Value = ele.Item(i + 1).innerText
            ElseIf Trim$(ele.Item(i).innerText) = "Publication Number" Then
                wsh.Cells(j + 1, "E").Value = ele.Item(i + 1).innerText
            ElseIf Trim$(ele.Item(i).innerText) = "Status" Then
                wsh.Cells(j + 1, "G").Value = ele.Item(i + 1).innerText
            ElseIf Trim$(ele.Item(i).innerText) = "Grant Date" Then
                wsh.Cells(j + 1, "F").Value = ele.Item(i + 1).innerText
            ElseIf Trim$(ele.Item(i).innerText) = "Filing Date" Then
                wsh.Cells(j + 1, "D").Value = ele.Item(i + 1).innerText
            End If
    Next i
    End With
    End If
Next cell
objIE.Quit
End Sub
```